# Credit figure in caption APA

Tags: bibliographies, biber, apa-style

I have to credit a figure according to APA guidelines. I found this image in the official guide: [image].

Is there any convenient way to do it in LaTeX?

The reference entry for the example shown above is:

```
@article{sampleentry,
author = {Wang, Xiaoye and Lind, Mats and Bingham, Geoffrey},
year = {2018},
month = {06},
pages = {},
title = {Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception},
volume = {44},
journal = {Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance},
doi = {10.1037/xhp0000553}
}
```

I tried this:

```
From \citetitle{testouille}, by \citeauthor{testouille}, \citeyear{testouille}, in \textit{\journalcite{testouille}}, \volumecite{testouille}(\numbercite{testouille}), p.\pagecite{testouille} (\doicite{testouille})
```

However, as you can imagine, you can't just cite the volume of number.

Edit:

Cicada provided a partial answer that I barely edited to get this:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}%
{\usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace} {%
\mkbibquote{\thefield{title}}%
\addcomma\addspace by \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
\addcomma\addspace \thefield{year}%
\addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{journaltitle}}%
\addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{volume}}%
\mkbibparens{\thefield{number}}%
\addcomma\addspace%
} {} {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
\addspace%
\mkbibparens{\url{\thefield{doi}}}%
\adddot%
}
```

With this answer, I managed to make an example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}

%\input{glossary-entries}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style = apa, autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{referencestest.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}%
{\usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace} {%
\mkbibquote{\thefield{title}}%
\addcomma\addspace by \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
\addcomma\addspace \thefield{year}%
\addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{journaltitle}}%
\addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{volume}}%
\mkbibparens{\thefield{number}}%
\addcomma\addspace%
} {} {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
\addspace%
\mkbibparens{\url{\thefield{doi}}}%
\adddot%
}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}



\chapterfont{\centering}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{3}




\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{Introduction}

Of course, the viability of autonomous cars won't be discussed in this document. It could be discussed in a next document.

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak


\section{Lorem}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\section{Ipsum}


\section{Lorem2}


\chapter{Ipsum2}

\section{Lorem3}

\section{Ipsum3}


\section{Lorem4}

From "Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception", by X. M. Wang, M. Lind and G. P. Bingham, 2018, \textit{Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance}, 44(10), p. 1513 (https://doi.org/10.1037/xhp0000553). Copyright 2018 by the American Psychological Association.

From \mycite{test2}



\end{document}
```

This is the entry test2:

```
@article{test2,
author = {Wang, Xiaoye Michael and Lind, Mats and Bingham, Geoffrey P.},
organization = {American Psychological Association},
year = {2018},
month = {06},
pages = {1513},
title = {Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception},
volume = {44},
number = {10},
journal = {Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance},
doi = {10.1037/xhp0000553}
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

The first paragraph is what I should get (first names's initials then last names). The second one is what I get. The doi isn't shown and there is no space between `M.` and `Bingham`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a common citation so you should use one of the available commands: `\cite`, `\textcite`, etc., depending on the packages used for managing the bibliography.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking this if all I had to do was ``\fullcite{sampleentry}``. ``\fullcite{sampleentry}`` would give me "Wang, X., Lind, M., & Bingham, G. (2018). Large continuous perspective change with noncoplanar
points enables accurate slant perception. Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and
Performance, 44. https://doi.org/10.1037/xhp0000553".

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWEB) of your current code for us to work on, which reproduces your specific problem.

Comment: (i) The bib entry is missing a `number={10},` field; (ii) the image is title-author-year style, yet apa style is author-year -- so something is out-of-sync  ;) ; (iii) a custom `DeclareCiteCommand` would do it; (iv) although I would expect the guidelines to, ... have a guide on this.

Comment: APA recommends the title to be cited first (only in-text) when crediting a table or a figure. Page 197 states ``Table 7.14 in Section 7.21 and Figures 7.3, 7.14, and 7.21 in Section 7.36
show copyright attributions for an adapted table when permission is not necessary, a reprinted figure when permission is not
necessary, a reprinted figure in the public domain, and a figure reprinted with permission, respectively.`` In all these cases and, of course, only in the text, the title is shown first.

Comment: That implies there should already be a command. Anyway, this (clunky) code gets 7/8s there: `\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}%
{\usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace}
{%
\mkbibquote{\thefield{title}}%
\addcomma\addspace
\mkbibbold{\printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}}%
\addcomma\addspace
\mkbibbold{\thefield{year}}%
\addcomma\addspace
\mkbibitalic{\thefield{journaltitle}}%
\addcomma\addspace
\mkbibitalic{\thefield{volume}}%
\mkbibparens{\thefield{number}}%
\addcomma\addspace%
}
{}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}%
\addspace%
\mkbibparens{\url{\thefield{doi}}}%
\adddot%
}`

Comment: Please supply an MWE, though. Which class and packages and biblatex styles etc affect the answer. e.g., apa7 (https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa7/apa7.pdf)

Comment: I couldn't provide a MWE because that's exactly what I was asking : which command should I enter? Your answer seems close to what I should get. With that, I managed to get a MWE and edited my message.

Comment: (a) Q: Document class `apa7` formats and typesets the doi correctly. Are you sure you want to use `report` class instead? (b) Q: In the image, from `by`  to `2018,`, all is bold. Do you want bold too? (c) There is a `\bibstring{by}` localization string already available. No need to hard-code it. (e) Prenote and postnote usage in general is `\mycite[From][1513]{test2}`. (f) Apologies: I don't use names (or dots, or initials), so I'll have to read the manual to find out how to format dotted initials in name lists. It would be something useful to know, in any case.

Comment: With another class, I wouldn't be able to use chapters. I tried to change my document class with ``apa`` and I would have to change everything by hand.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of class, packages, options and command usage and settings will affect how (and if) you can do things -- so you still have to make a choice in that space. For example, handling urls via custom coding instead of letting `apa7` take care of it, if you are constrained to use some other class.

Independently of those matters, and after some testing, and using documentclass `apa7` with biblatex option `style = apa6,`; putting given names first with `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}` and switching on initials with biblatex option `giveninits=true,`; then defining a `by` bibstring; and adding the copyright notice to the bibentry; and de-cluttering the MWE to a minimum -- a custom, but still clunky, citation command (named `\copyrightcite` and used like this: `\copyrightcite[From][1513]{test2}`) produces the following, with manual coding output shown in comparison with the cite output:

[image: copyrightcite]

Original image:

[image: original requirement]

Note: The reference bibentry still does not match the image. A bibentry with `author = {Wang, Xiaoye and Lind, Mats and Bingham, Geoffrey},` will never produce `X. M. Wang, M. Lind, and G. P. Bingham`, so something is still out-of-sync in the guidelines source.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@article{test2,
author = {Wang, Xiaoye and Lind, Mats and Bingham, Geoffrey},
date = {2018-06},
pages = {},
title = {Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception},
title+an:copyright = {="Copyright 2018 by the American Psychological Association"},
volume = {44},
number={10},
journal = {Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1037/xhp0000553}
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass[jou,colorlinks]{apa7}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[style = apa6, 
sortcites=true,
sorting=nyt,
autocite=inline,
giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{given-family}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
  \NewBibliographyString{by}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
by = {by}
}
%\addbibresource{referencestest.bib}

  


\DeclareCiteCommand{\copyrightcite}%
{\usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace} {%
\mkbibquote{\thefield{title}}%
\addcomma\addspace \mkbibbold{\bibstring{by}\addspace\printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
\addcomma\addspace \thefield{year}%
\addcomma\addspace} \mkbibitalic{\thefield{journaltitle}}%
\addcomma\addspace \mkbibitalic{\thefield{volume}}%
\mkbibparens{\thefield{number}}%
\addcomma\addspace%
} {} {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
\addspace%
\mkbibparens{\url{\thefield{doi}}}%
\adddot%
\hasfieldannotation[title][copyright]{%
\adddot\addspace%
\getfieldannotation[title][copyright]\adddot}{}%
}

%\usepackage{fullpage}
%
%\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\restoreparindent
%
%\makeindex


\begin{document}

%\pagenumbering{Roman}
%
%
%
%\sectionfont{\centering}
%
%\pagebreak
%\setcounter{page}{3}
%
%
%
%
%\tableofcontents{}
%
%
%\section{Introduction}
%
%Of course, the viability of autonomous cars won't be discussed in this document. It could be discussed in a next document.
%
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%
%\pagebreak
%
%
%\section{Lorem}
%
%\section{Ipsum}
%
%
%\section{Lorem2}
%
%
%\section{Ipsum2}
%
%\section{Lorem3}
%
%\section{Ipsum3}
%
%
%\section{Lorem4}
\section{Source}
\begin{quotation}\noindent
\begin{verbatim}
@article{test2,
author = {Wang, Xiaoye and Lind, Mats and Bingham, Geoffrey},
date = {2018-06},
pages = {},
title = {Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception},
title+an:copyright = {="Copyright 2018 by the American Psychological Association"},
volume = {44},
number={10},
journal = {Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1037/xhp0000553}
}

\end{verbatim}
\end{quotation}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\section{Manual}
From "Large Continuous Perspective Change With Noncoplanar Points Enables Accurate Slant Perception", by X. M. Wang, M. Lind and G. P. Bingham, 2018, \textit{Journal of Experimental Psychology: Human Perception and Performance}, 44(10), p. 1513 (https://doi.org/10.1037/xhp0000553). Copyright 2018 by the American Psychological Association.

\section{Custom: \textbackslash copyrightcite}
\copyrightcite[From][1513]{test2}

\section{Usual: \textbackslash cite}
\cite[From][1513]{test2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: "you can't just cite the volume of number." -- the `\citefield` command is available (manual, 3.8.7 Low-level Commands), such that `\citefield{test2}{volume}`, with no particular formatting applied, gives `44`.